# Where can I find the vector geometric shapes svg elements used in design editor

Tags: typescript, svg, editor, fabricjs

There are lot design editor like canva, vistacreate, adobe express. All have various styles of elements/objects/shapes they use. Is there a database where I can find. Some common places are flaticons.com or nounproject.com

Wondering if there is better option?

I tried nounproject but it has too much icons

Answer (score 1):

Check https://iconify.design/ they try to combine a lot of sources into one. If you're using some design tools like Figma or Sketch they have plugins too, allowing you to place them directly into your projects.

For list of all icon-packs they provide, go here: https://icon-sets.iconify.design/